# How to set window size using phantomjs and selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to get a full sized browser screenshot with phantomjs driven by python webdriver . right now my screenshot is measured at 927 x 870, I'd like to reset it. I have tried:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1400,1000))
```

based on [this source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/f29lxBQNLqY/_Pyi7j9EEVQJ), but this is giving syntax errors.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because that's Java. Python's documentation is [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html).

There's a method called `set_window_size`, which is defined [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py):

```
driver.set_window_size(1400,1000)
```

Further reading:  [How to get window size, resize or maximize window using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/02/23/how-to-get-window-size-resize-or-maximize-window-using-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: For PHP it will be (from within context):

`$this->getSession()->getDriver()->resizeWindow(1400, 1000);`

Answer (score -3):

For Java, the Dimension import has to be:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
```

and it won't give syntax errors